# How to receive new data on an InputStream from a socket continuously

Tags: java, sockets

My java code is this

```
package pack.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class ReceiveHex 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
   {
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.121.146", 6866);
        byte[] data = new byte[5];

        while(true)
        {
           InputStream stream = s.getInputStream();
           stream.read(data);
           System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(data));
           data= null;
           //stream.reset();
       }
   }
}
```

I want to receive data continuosly from the server in the array and print it. Right now I am getting 0000000000
How to achieve this, Please help me with this.

Comment: You should always look at how many bytes you read.  Becuase you are reading so slowly (you have a very small buffer) and printing it to the console which is even slower, this may appear to work most of the time, but I suggest using a larger buffer and using the length returned by read()

Comment: You are getting `0000000000` but what are you expecting? and why? What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to analize read return value, it is the actual number of bytes read into data

```
int len = stream.read(data);
...
```

if it is -1 it means EOS.

Alternatively you could read / print by byte

```
int byte = stream.read();
...
```

Comment: @ Evgeniy Dorofeev
I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are reading from a socket (which I'm assuming refers to `java.net.Socket`) data may not be available all the time.

Looking at the documentation for InputStream.read(byte[]) we see:

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

The method returns a integer telling you the number of bytes that can be read (and was read) at this given point, blocking only when **some** data is available. Note: This means the method may not necessarily fill your byte array.

For example it may be that your byte array has a size of 1000 bytes but only 2 bytes were available to be read at the time. In this case only the first two bytes of the array would be filled and the integer 2 will be returned by the read() method.

A "more" correct way of reading from an InputStream is shown below:

```
int read; //Our read counter

while((read = stream.read(data)) != -1){
    //Manipulate data over here.
    //Note that the read variable contains the actual numbers of bytes read.

    //E.G:
    byte[] readdata = Arrays.copyOf(data, read); //Gives a copy of our read data, truncated to the read size.
    System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(readdata));
}
//End of stream, no more data available.
```

With every loop we check that the read() method doesn't return -1 (signifying the end of stream [i.e. no more data available]). Inside the loop we can perform operations on the data read **taking note of the read variable**.

The solution will read data "continuously" should they be available. Given that no new data is available the currently executing thread will block at the read() method until more data is available.

Comment: @ CPU Terminator
I am still getting 000000000
                   000000000
                   000000000 so on

Comment: @Shanx What are you expecting? Perhaps your code is failing on the transmission side.

Comment: @ CPU Terminator
On the server side i am sending like this
if(send(remote_fd,combine,sizeof(combine),0) == -1)

Comment: @Shanx Please add your full sending code to the question. The line you posted doesn't tell me anything much. What is the `send()` method and what is this `combine` variable? Please add these to the question.

Comment: @ CPU Terminator
I got it, The problem was on the server side.

Comment: @Shanx Glad you solved your issue.